# oracle query to round time to lower 15 minute window

Tags: oracle, datetime

I have a query which rounds the time to the nearest 15 minutes window:

```
Select     Sysdate,
           Trunc (Sysdate) + ( Round ( (Sysdate - Trunc (Sysdate))* 96)/ 96)
FROM       dual;
```

However, I don't want the nearest but the lower 15 minutes window.

e.g. 1:

> Time                 19:57:03
>   Above query output   20:00:00
>   Required output      19:45:00

e.g 2:

> Time                 17:18:00
>   Above query output   17:15:00
>   required output      17:15:00

The second example is correct but the first one rounds to `20:00` as its nearer point. However I want query to output `19:45` for first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Floor` And `Ceil` Concept.

```
Select     Sysdate,
           Trunc (Sysdate) + ( Round (floor(Sysdate - Trunc (Sysdate))* 96)/ 96)
FROM       dual;
```

For reference, Please visit [Here](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/from-floor-to-ceiling-and-other-functional-cases)

Comment: THanks for the quick reply, i was in middle of immediate changes and this helped me with it.

Comment: And also, please mark this as the answer, if it is the solution to your Question. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

You just need a `FLOOR` function after `ROUND` function -

```
Select SYSDATE,
       TRUNC(SYSDATE) + (ROUND(FLOOR((SYSDATE - TRUNC (SYSDATE))* 96))/ 96)
FROM DUAL;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c1f6e370e045d06b811548ede3522e69) is the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't give the right solution for me as the default precision for round is 0 and the calculation gets rounded off to 0.

To get the lower 15 min window, floor needs to be used, not both round and floor.

The code that worked for me was

```
SELECT SYSDATE, TRUNC(SYSDATE) + FLOOR((SYSDATE - TRUNC(SYSDATE))*96) / 96 AS time_lower_15_min
, TRUNC(SYSDATE) + ROUND((SYSDATE - TRUNC(SYSDATE))*96) / 96 AS time_15_min
FROM dual
```